# Remove Columns from Matrix in Matlab based on columns values stored in Vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I am trying to remove columns from a matrix. The columns which are to be removed, their indexes are mentioned in another vector. What is the best way to do that.

a= [

```
 2    43    65    77     3     9    89

 3    45    65    75    22     6    62

33    64     3     3     2     6    36

 3     5     6     3    66     5    15

 9     4     5    66     4     4    14

22     3    44    66     3     3    23

99     4     4     3    32    99    70
```

]

c = [2,4,5]

so, using c I want a = [

```
 2    65     9    89

 3    65     6    62

33     3     6    36

 3     6     5    15

 9     5     4    14

22    44     3    23

99     4    99    70
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [`Matrix indexing in MATLAB`](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). This is a straightforward operation as follows:

```
a(:,c)=[];
```